# How to return the value of JQuery code?

Tags: jquery, return-value

This may seem like a noob question, but I can't seem to do anything about it. I know quite some javascript and I'm been trying this JQuery plugin which checks if two elements overlap. http://jquer.in/helpful-jquery-plugins-for-html5-websites/overlaps/
I have this code:

```
$('#elm1').overlaps('#elm2')
```

The thing is how do I get the value from it. When a try an alert with it in a variable I get [object Object] and when I put it in a function I just get the code.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's not so noob question, as [**this plugin**](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-overlaps/blob/master/jquery.overlaps.js) returns value in a non-trivial way:

> The second mode is to compare one set of elements against another and
> return only the elements that overlap.
>
> `$('#div1').overlaps('#div2');`

In this example, if `#div1` and `#div2` overlap, the returned jQuery object will have both of them. If not, only `#div1`.

So the solution is to check the length of the plugin's resulting object - and compare it with sum of lengths of the compared jQuery objects. If these are the same, the elements overlap; if not, they don't. )

In this particular example, you can just compare result's length with 2, like this:

```
if ( $('#div1').overlaps('#div2').length === 2 ) { // they overlap }
```

... as in valid DOM there can be exactly one element with a given ID.

Comment: Thanks. This wasn't actually the problem. The thing was that one element was in a div. I don't know why that changed anything, but it worked after I took it out. And instead of returning the elements that were overlapping it retuned one's and zero's.